# Is there a way to disable my discord bot's direct messages in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have 2 bots and another one of them includes alot of slash commands, I don't want anyone to have access to use these commands in the bot's direct messages.

I have tried to find a way to disable my bot's direct messages but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `guild_only` decorator/check while building your command. This ensures, despite the commands maybe showing up, that one can't use them in the direct messages of the bot:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.guild_only()
# [Rest of your code]
```

Read more about it here: [Command.guild_only](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=commands%20guild_only#discord.app_commands.Command.guild_only)